# Shared app getting stopped in other device

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-install-apk

I am new to android app development field.I recently created an app and it is working in my device as expected.For being particular ,the app in my device is installed and run directly via android studio.

The problem is that whenever I am sharing the apk file of this app to any other device it is getting stopped while opening the app after proper installation.

Can any body suggest the underlying problem or the way to check it?

Comment: When you say "it is getting stopped", do you mean that you app crashes? Also you need to show us your LogCat.

Comment: Are you requesting the "dangerous" permissions ***at runtime*** on Marshmallow and above devices?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it will crash. If you want to share APK you should build APK. It will give you app-debug named apk. You can share that APK with anyone.

The app you ran from android studio won't run on other devices.

[image]